# splitting srdf, urdf files

Tags: ros, urdf, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have a srdf file (and as a matter of fact a urdf file as well) that are split into multiple files?

I was reading the docs and an  doesn't seem to exist.

Why do I want this? I have a robot with a modular design.

Or will I have to write a script to generate these files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276125/splitting-srdf,-urdf-files/) by [fbelmonteklein](https://answers.ros.org/users/32656/fbelmonteklein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For URDF: see [wiki/xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro).

For SRDF: this is not natively supported, but there are people that use xacro there as well. See [personalrobotics/herb_description](https://github.com/personalrobotics/herb_description) for a(n) (random) example.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1